# Thread Vs Async call

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, nsurlconnection, nsthread

I wanted to know the best between Spawning a Thread or making a async call using NSURLConnection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> An NSURLConnection object provides
>   support to perform the loading of a
>   URL request. The interface for
>   NSURLConnection is sparse, providing
>   only the controls to start and cancel
>   asynchronous loads of a URL request.

i.e. NSURLConnection *only* supports asynchronous loading of content.   Even the [sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest%3areturningResponse%3aerror%3a) method is really just a wrapper around async loading that blocks until done.

That class reference has links to both the programming guide and numerous examples.