# iPhone: Does http supports Asynchronous method?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iOS 4.x devices. I am implementing a communication module, where-in program sends file(some times multiple files at a time) to the server periodically. I am implementing code using the following function. I would like to know, does Apple's http code like below supports "Asynchronous" method (or) Should i have to use some third party API's like "ASIHTTPRequest" to support Asynchronous call in my function. Please advise.

```
-(void) HttpUpload : (UIImage *) image :(NSString *) fileNameStr
```

{

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image, 90);
NSString *urlString = @"http://iphone.zcentric.com/test-upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// header now..
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// Create body of the post..
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", fileNameStr] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

// lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(responseString);
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. My question again is, does ASIHttpRequest from Apple? (or) Apple's http post query code(my code written in original query) support Asynchronous call? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` Then implement the delegate methods.

**Edit**
Try changing this in your code
remove these lines

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

add this in there

```
NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; //Warning. this is a leak. You have to use a propery so you can properly release later.
```

add these delegates:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //Handle the error
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
  //If you need to handle partial data do that here
  //This method can be called several times. So, may be you have to append the data in an NSMutableData object
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
  //If you need to handle the response do that here
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
  //This callback is the last one
}
```

Comment: This is not doing Asynchronous call.

Comment: it does. Take a look at the docs for NSURLConnection. That is what the docs say... NSURLConnection’s delegate methods allow an object to receive informational callbacks about the asynchronous load of a URL request. Other delegate methods provide facilities that allow the delegate to customize the process of performing an asynchronous URL load. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445605/thread-vs-async-call

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. One last question, i'm sending some files to the server from the device via my code mentioned in this query. Is there any tutorial to go through sending the files via NSURLConnection from device to server?